# No background/wallpaper in Ubuntu 12.04 - what to do?

Tags: desktop-background

This is how my desktop looks like after moving Firefox window arround:

[image]
The background just doesn't redraw, there is no wallpaper. It is like that since update to 12.04 - it was the same in 11.10 but I had special intel drivers then that fixed this problem. Doesn't seem to be fixed in 12.04 even with the ppa I was using then. What can I do? I couldn't find anything about it on Google because results were unrelated. :(
I have Samsung RF-511 notebook with Nvidia card turned off - so it's using only Intel from i7.

Comment: Please paste the link to the screenshot and someone else can embed it as an image.

Comment: Here it is: [link](http://wieza.iq.pl/media/screenshot.jpg) - after last update though it's even worse because Unity is now not displaying anything (it's black - I can click icons, but don't see anything).

Answer (score 1):

After a long time and update to 12.10 I finally solved my probelm - in Ubuntu 12.10 to solve it I had to just... set a different wallpaper. Aparently I had empty wallpaper set or sth.

Comment: there is a setting in dconf/gconf that allows to make the desktop transparent. This is default set to NO and is set to NO again when you set a wallpaper to your desktop. You probably has this set to YES (there are some options in compiz settings that do this).

Comment: transparency of the desktop wallpaper?.. schema please..

Answer (score 0):

You may try logging in using Ubuntu 2D--at login, click the gear icon, select Ubuntu 2D, and continue login. Hope this helps. If not, you may want to try Lubuntu. `sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop` in a terminal.